# How to connect devstack from java application

Tags: jclouds, devstack

I installed devstack. I'm trying to develop a java web application that can connect openstack through RESTful, so that we get stored sample data from openstack into our application.

What are the steps needed to do and how to start. If any sample application or links for that plz share to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read through the entire [jclouds OpenStack Guide](http://jclouds.apache.org/guides/openstack/). It will show you how to connect to any OpenStack cloud including DevStack.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use [Dasein Cloud abstraction library](http://www.dasein.org) where you will be able to use a Java abstraction layer to connect to the OpenStack's object storage, but you will also be able to migrate to another cloud storage, like Amazon S3, without making any changes to your application code.